# catch error created after loading page in webBrowser Control in C#.net

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I would like to know how to handle the runtime error generated on the page after being rendered in the webbrowser Control in C#.net, is there a way to catch it or prevent it from showing in the forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How to handle script errors as a WebBrowser control host](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/261003)

Managed Wrapper

1. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/ExtendedWebBrowser.aspx
2. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/csEXWB.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the call that throws an error in a try catch block

`try{
//code that throws an error
}catch (Exception e){
//handle the error here.
}`

Comment: it wont work since the error was generated on the HTML page rendered in the control and not in the application.

Comment: ah. Can you check the error code after displaying and then quickly change it. Although that might not be the best solution.